# Setting Selected value in a Angular Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angularjs 1.5.5

I have a simple `Select` which works fine:

```
    <select ng-model="selectedPart">
        <option ng-repeat="optionPart in parts"  value="{{optionPart.Id}}">{{optionPart.Title}}</option>
    </select>
```

When I set the id as a string, the `Select` renders that correctly:

```
 $scope.selectedPart = "1";
```

When I set it to an Int from an object, no change is made.

```
 $scope.selectedPart = $scope.parts[0].Id;
```

Why does the `Int` not update the `Select` but the `string` does, and how would I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this instead

```
<select ng-model="selectedPartId"
    ng-options="part.Id as part.Title for part in parts">
</select>
```

Note that I've changed the model to reflect that you're selecting an `id` and not a `parts` entry.

If you did want to bind an object, try this

```
<select ng-model="selectedPart"
    ng-options="part.Title for part in parts track by part.Id">
</select>
```

You could then assign it via `$scope.selectedPart = $scope.parts[0];`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can do it:

```
1. $scope.parts = [{
                        id: 2,
                        Title: 'XX'
                    }, {
                        id: 5,
                        Title: 'XXXX'
                    }, {
                        id: 8,
                        Title: 'XXVVV'
                    }];

                    $scope.selectedPart = $scope.parts[1];

                    <select ng-options="part as part.Title for part in parts track by part.id" ng-model="selectedPart"></select>

2. $scope.parts = [{
                        id: 2,
                        Title: 'XX'
                    }, {
                        id: 5,
                        Title: 'XXXX'
                    }, {
                        id: 8,
                        Title: 'XXVVV'
                    }];

                    $scope.selectedPart = $scope.parts[1].id;

                    <select ng-options="part.id as part.Title for part in parts" ng-model="selectedPart"></select>
```